# Ionic 4, Angular 8 and HTTP interceptor

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I'm building mobile app with Ionic 4 and Angular 8 and can't make my HTTP interceptor working. 
I reviewed all the examples of interceptors here but none fits my need or simply do not work any more.

The only difference against the regular Angular 8 version is the first line where token is read from the storage. Original Angular 8 code reads such things synchronously and doesn't need subscription thus it works. This one here is Ionic storage which calls local resources in async way.

Here is my code:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  from(this.storage.get('id_token')).subscribe(res => {
    const idToken = res;
    if (idToken) {
      const cloned = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('token', idToken)});
      return next.handle(cloned);
    } else {
      console.log('Unauthorized calls are redirected to login page');
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap(
          event => {
            // logging the http response to browser's console in case of a success
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              // console.log('api call success :', event);
            }
          },
          error => {
            // logging the http response to browser's console in case of a failure
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (error.status === 401) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
              }
            }
          }
        )
      );
    }
  });
}
```

In this shape it compiles but my IDE reports: TS2355 (function has to return a value).
What is wrong or missing here ? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like you're trying to do 2 things in 1 interceptor:

- add the Bearer token
- if error code is 401 - redirect to home page

Also, you'll access the storage at EVERY request which is expensive.

Here's what I did:

- Create an auth service and manage the token there
- In auth service have a BehaviourSubject that stores the token's last value

And here it goes:

```
// JWT interceptor
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';


@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        const currentAuthToken = this.authenticationService.currentAuthTokenValue;
        if (currentAuthToken && currentAuthToken.token) {
            const headers = {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${currentAuthToken.token}`,
            };
            if (request.responseType === 'json') {
                headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            }
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: headers
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

authenticationService.currentAuthTokenValue is just a getter that returns current subject's value

```
public get currentAuthTokenValue(): AuthToken {
    return this.currentAuthTokenSubject.value;
}
```

Also another interceptor for error:

```
// Error interceptor
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout().then(() => {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.error.detail || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it does, I implemented "your way" and it finally works. One question: why would you create 2 separate interceptors for success and failure, I sticked to just one and I'm happy about it?

Comment: Another question perhaps: you're saying that accessing storage ins expensive. It wasn't (or rather is not) in regular Angular app, why it is in Ionic? This is after all local resource, immediately available.

Comment: 2 interceptors, because it's a separation of concerns. If in the future I'd need to do something about error 403 (forbidden) or even 404, I can just modify the error interceptor. If I'll need to do something depending on the 'audience' field from JWT token I would only edit the JWT interceptor. Of course, you can write it in 1 file if you want to. In my case I started with 2, also I find it more readable.

Comment: Anything that is async takes some time is expensive... I don't know about your case, in my case I use @ionic/storage, that will use under the hood for Android IndexedDB, and for iOS will use Web SQL (because if the iPhone lacks RAM it will delete your localstorage, and you don't want that if the good functionning  your app is depending on something in your storage). Accessing this layers is time consuming...

Comment: Using RxJS to combine different requests in a single scenario, will result in accessing the storage too often. For example, to show some stats on the home page, 3 different requests are done and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that. In regular Abgular app running in the browser accessing local storage (also in the browser) is not async and is lightning fast. So no need to do all of that gymnastics. It's good to know however it is not the case in mobile world. Thanks again