# Token authorization error if read from local storage ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working with Ionic, I need to send token to get the api data.
The below code works fine

```
this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({

      Authorization:"Token "+'d5213668d34013c9087273a5efab6d39d6d8bfb9'

    })
```

but when tried to read data from local storage, not getting the api data. Showing authorization error. The code i tried is

```
this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({

      Authorization:"Token "+(localStorage.getItem('token')

    })
```

when console.log((localStorage.getItem('token'))) is tried printing the same token - "d5213668d34013c9087273a5efab6d39d6d8bfb9"
Checked the type of both Both are giving string

Comment: Trying to read from local storage every API call can be very taxing. Take a look into using a service to save the token and even using a HTTP Interceptor would be better. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173960/6559330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put in API
rather than Local

//get code
//api code (header value, where getapI CALLED

```
this.headers = {
      Authorization: "Token " + this.getLoginCred(),
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      Accept: "application/json",
    };
```

//my getLoginCred() function is as follows:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('LoginData');
    if (data != null && data != '' && data != undefined) {
      return JSON.parse(window.atob(data.split('.')[1]));
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
```

I Do this code and my code runned Perfectly.
WITHOUT ANY ERROR OR WARNING..

Comment: I changed the data to json and changed to content type as json, it works

var dec = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('token')));

    this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({

      Authorization: "Token " + dec,

     "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",

     Accept: "application/json",

    })

Answer (score 0):

You're last code snippet above is missing a closing `)`

```js
this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({

      Authorization:"Token "+(localStorage.getItem('token'))

    })
```

...*Definitely still check out Brian's comment!*

Comment: that is typing error here. Correctly tried in code but doesn't work

Comment: Now that I think of it, I've had this issue years ago too. It's inexplicable to me, but I worked around by simply assigning the value of the Authorization Header just before I created the headers:
```
let Authorization= "Token "+(localStorage.getItem('token'));
this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization
});
```